# Magento 2.2 - Sorting product in category page by position not working

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, sorting, product-sorting

I'm trying sort products in category page by `position`. But Magento2 does not react to changes.

[image]

Any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you take the collection? Try adding `addAttributeToSort('attribute_code', 'sort_order')`

Answer (score 2):

It is Magento2.2 default bug. Please follow this to solve your problem.

Create `etc/di.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" />
</config>
```

Create `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php` file. Copy core `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection.php` file in your module and put below code in that file.

Replace line no. 366 to 388 in `Collection.php`.

```
            'search_result.'. TemporaryStorage::FIELD_SCORE . ' ' . $this->relevanceOrderDirection
        );
    }
    return parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function _beforeLoad()
{
    /*
    * This order is required to force search results be the same
    * for the same requests and products with the same relevance
    * NOTE: this does not replace existing orders but ADDs one more
    */
    $this->setOrder('entity_id');

    return parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    return parent::_beforeLoad();
 }

/**
```

Comment: Please update full file

Comment: It doesn't work. Just tested on mag 2.2.3. Plz share your complete code.

Comment: does Magento have more default bugs ? :)